# How to get component value on index.html template in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

Basically scenario is that i am getting URL parameter value in my home component and now i want to use this value on my index.html page.how we can do this?

Comment: How do you want to use it? As a title?

Comment: As in footer value

Comment: Why don't you have the footer in app.component.html?

Comment: i am using header and footer on index.html

Comment: It is not clear question.

Comment: You should `NOT` use javascript to modify the DOM because Angular provides you different way to achieve that, and most important Angular use its "personal" DOM. `Reflection` is a thing. Move the footer and the header from the index.html inside two components and use `@Input` or `Subject/BehaviorSubject` to update the components.

Answer (score 1):

You could use native javascript to set some text.

```js
public class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        document.querySelector('#foo').innerText = 'bar';
    }
}
```

Or just move the header and footer from your index.html into your app.component.html. Propably the simplest way to solve your issue.

Comment: can you please let me know if i want to add script file in app.component.html how i can do this?? like currently i am going with your solution to move header footer in app component but i am getting the header footer from some external source or third party. But i don't able to load "script.js" on my appcomponent.html template same script.js is loading on index.html. I am doing like this   <script src="https://script.js"> "script.js can be any third party file name

Comment: If you can't change how the footer is loaded, then you probably have to use the native js way.